# Jquery mouseleave setTimeout don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in jQuery:

```
$( ".name" )
  .on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("ul").css({"font-size": "20px",
    'color': "red"});
   })
  .on( "mouseleave", function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(this).find("ul").css({"font-size": "12px",
      'color': "blue"});
    }, 5000);
  });
```

The first part is working, but the second part is broken.

Why is the `setTimeout` on `mouseleave` not working?

Comment: `this` resolves as the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping problem. `$(this)` inside the `setTimeout` doesn't refer to `$('.name')`. You can fix this by setting a variable for `this` at the correct level and referring to that.

```
.on("mouseleave", function() {

    var self = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        self.find("ul").css({
            "font-size": "12px",
            'color': "blue"
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(this), try passing in event as an argument and using $(event.target)